# Extract certain text from a string with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I tried to extract a coded string from a string, for instance,

```
$string = 'Louise Bourgeois and Tracey Emin: Do Not Abandon Me [date]Until 31 August 2011[ /date ]';

$description = preg_replace('/\[(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([date]+)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\](.*?)\[(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([\/date]+)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\]/is', '',$string);

$date = preg_replace('/\[(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([date]+)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\](.*?)\[(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([\/date]+)(?:&nbsp;|\s)*\]/is', '$3',$string);

echo $date;
```

result:

```
Louise Bourgeois and Tracey Emin: Do Not Abandon Me /date
```

intended result:

```
Until 31 August 2011
```

I got the `$description` right but I can't get the `[date]` right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a rather simpler form would do:

```
#.*?\[\s*?date\s*?\](.*)\[\s*?/date\s*?\].*#
```

for instance?

Comment: thought of that but it fails when you have spacing in the tags like this [   date ].

Comment: @lauthiamkok: So would you say that the text you are trying to parse is irregular?

Comment: Changed it to match, will only work for spaces and such. try it.

Comment: @ jasonbar, yes it could be that case, because the user might put  [ date ] instead of  [date].

Answer (score 0):

```
([date]+)
```

This is going to look for one-or-more sequences of letters containing `d`, `a`, `t`, and/or `e`. `[]` are regex metacharacters for character classes and will not treated as literal characters for matching purposes. You'd probably want:

```
(\[date\])   and    (\[\/date\])
```

to properly match those opening/closing "tags".

Comment: thought of that but it fails when you have spacing in the tags like this [ date ]. but the main problem is that I will still get `Louise Bourgeois and Tracey Emin: Do Not Abandon Me Until 31 August 2011` but not `Until 31 August 2011` which is what am after... is it possible?